# Devise auth fails with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In devise initializer configured pepper and secret_key. When I'm trying to sign in, I still on the sign in page. When I sign up, user persists in db, but doesn't sign in. I've tried to write custom controller, when I've put sign_in(:user, User.first) — doesn't make sense. User can not be authenticated.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try give you some general answers and you can say if it's good or not, anyway they are just possible answers.

Have you tried to log in using rails console? And during this login did you see the errors in the log ?

Here's one way I was able to do it:

```
>> ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
>> app.post('/sign_in', {"user"=>{"login"=>"login", "password"=>"password"}})
```

Then you can do:

```
 >> app.get '/some_other_path_that_only_works_if_logged_in'
 >> pp app.response.body
```

Other idea is to redirect for a specific page if login failed:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated